# Prove that graph G is periphery of H when all edges have eccentricity 1 or not equal to 1

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that given an undirected non-trivial graph $G, G$ is the periphery of some other graph $H$, if and only if:

a)for each vertex $ v \in V(G)$ , $ecc(v)=1 $
 or
 b)for each vertex  $ v \in V(G)$ , $ecc(v)\neq1 $

$V(G)$ being the set of vertices of $G$ , $ecc(v)$ being the eccentricity of vertex $v$
The periphery of a graph is the set of vertices with eccentricity equal to the diameter of the graph (diameter being the maximum eccentricity).

The first case seems a bit easier, as from what i can tell, graphs with eccentricity 1 are the complete graphs $K_n$ , so maybe i can construct some graph for every $n$ number of vertices that has G as the perimeter.
For the other case i don't really know where to start.